# Search for a Item in ListView and get its properties

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, listview

How can I search for an Item in ListView and get all SubItems from the found Item?

**Example:**

```
Software        Date            Version         Key
-------------   --------------  --------------  ---------------
Microsoft       03-04-2014      1.0.0           gfd809432hf
Adobe           04-08-2008      0.8.6           nbv89034hsa
```

In the properties of the ListView, 'Software', 'Date', 'Version' & 'Key' are the Columns. I added 'Microsoft' & 'Adobe' as Item. Then i added  '03-04-2014' as a SubItem (under the Item properties) and so on.

**I want to get all subitems from Adobe and paste it in an array.**

Comment: The subitems where are stored?

Comment: The SubItems are stored in each 'Software' entry e.g. 'Microsoft' has '03-04-2014' '1.0.0' and 'gfd809432hf' as SubItem.

Comment: Post your code I'm a bit confused

Comment: Those are not SubItems but properties

Comment: I hope my edit is now more exact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ListViewItem lvi = listView1.FindItemWithText("searchMe");
string s = "";
foreach (ListViewItem lvsi in lvi.SubItems) s += lvsi.Text + " ";
```